# How to get value from textarea in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on Laravel 5.2 and I'm finding difficult to fetch value from `textarea` inside controller.

I've tried `$request->input` just like we used to fetch values from inputs but it's not working in my case. I have done this far.

### managecategories.blade.php

```
<form action="/addcategories" method="post" id="addcategory_form" name="addcategory_form">
    <div>
        <label>Insert Category</label>
        <input type="text" name="category" data-validation="required" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Insert Category</label>
        <textarea  name="category" data-validation="required" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$" row="5" col="200"></textarea> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Category" id="category_btn">
</form>
```

### AdminAjaxController

```
public function addcategory(Request $request)
{
    $category=$request->input('category');
    $category_description=$request->input('description');
    $insertcategory= DB::insert('insert into categories(category_name,description) values(?, ?)',[$category,$category_description]);
    $fetch_category= DB::select('select category_name,category_id from categories');
    return response()->json(array('add_category' => $category),200);
}
```

Comment: Both fields are named `category`. Change the name on the textarea to `description`

Comment: oops pity me! thanks man! :)

Comment: @BhavikBamania You should post an answer and accept it, as to not leave the question open.

Comment: @Daniel yeah will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops Pity me! Both fields are named category. I need to change the name on the textarea to description caught by Aynber.

here is the edited and correct code

```
<form action="/addcategories" method="post" id="addcategory_form" name="addcategory_form">
<div>
    <label>Insert Category</label>
    <input type="text" name="category" data-validation="required" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Insert Category</label>
    <textarea  name="description" data-validation="required" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$" row="5" col="200"></textarea> 
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Category" id="category_btn">
```

thanks mate! :)